# Can I disable select2 in just one simple_form of my code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, simple-form

I need to insert a dropdown list in a simple_form collection. I added the line below and it did not work. When I click in the dropdown-box nothing happens and it should show me the collection of itmes (2 email addresses).

`= f.input :recipient, :collection => %w[contato@wit.com suporte@wit.com]`

When I inspected the code I noticed that everytime I cliked in the dropdown-box something was changing in the code.

From this:

[image]

To that:

[image]

Then I went to check what was select2 and started to suspect that it migth be the reason why the dropdown-list was not working. Are there any way I can disable Select2 at this part of the code so I can test if this is the reason why my code does not work ? Why is html showing two containers that apparently do the same thing and why the email adresses do not appear ? Find below html which shows select and span containers.

[image]

Comment: Inspect the select2 and try to change the z-index. may be the span which shows the option have less z-index value than the div wrapper.

Comment: I am not sure I did it correctly but it did not work.

Comment: I guess this might be the problem...

Comment: At some point in the code there is this line: `$reveal-zindex: 1005`. The file name is app/assets/stylesheets/frameworks/foundation/_settings.scss. It is apparently the only place where z-index is established.

Comment: Above I will print the html code. Apparently, to me, there are two containers which are fighting each other (Select and span). Can that be the reason why this is not working besides z-index ?

Comment: Is select2 working properly in other than this popup??

Comment: You were rigth ! I finally found the correct span (select 2) to inspect. Once I put z-index equal or above 1005 the dropdown list appeared. Now I need to understand how to change it permanently. I tried to use the id in the span but failed. Should I create another question to learn it ?

Comment: You can fix it by using the css. with id of the select you will get the span inside that select2. change the z-index